# How set displayName to a React stateless component with memo?

Tags: reactjs, memo

This is a exemple the implementation of the stateless component:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

const Create = memo(props => {
    return <div id={props.id}>CREATE TEST</div>;
});

Create.displayName = "Create";

export default Create;
```

In React Developer Tools on Chrome is displayed like a Anonymous component (highlighted line):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign`:

```
const Create = memo(
  Object.assign(props => {
    return <div id={props.id}>CREATE TEST</div>;
  }, { displayName: 'Create' } )
)
```

You can also look at [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18026), you may use any workaround solutions if above solution isn't helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! Can it affect performance?

Comment: No. It doesn't. However, displayName  is used for debugging purpose only.

Answer (score 6):

As for every component in React, React DevTools look for either the `name` or `displayName` property of the component itself.

You can, therefore, simply set the `displayName` property:

```js
export const SomeButton = memo(() => { ... });
SomeButton.displayName = 'SomeButton';
```

But `memo()` itself retrieves the name from the passed component, so you can also use a named function expression instead of an arrow function:

```js
export const SomeButton = memo(function SomeButton() { ... });
```